# Is connectedness subspace invariant?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

If $X$ is a topological space and $Y$ is a subspace of $X$, then is it true that any subset $Z$ of $Y$ which is connected in the topology of $X$, is also connected in the subspace topology of $Y$?

I believe it is not true.

Explanation: Consider $X$ to be the topological space $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the cofinite topology. Let $Y=\{1,2,3\}$ and $Z=\{1,2\}$. Then the subspace topology on $Y$ is the discrete topology, as $\{1\}=\{2,3\}^c\cap Y$, and so on. Therefore, $Z$ is not connected in the subspace topology of $Y$. However $Z$ is connected in the topology of $X$, as any two open set in $X$ have non-empty intersection.

However, is my query true for metric spaces? If so, what property of a metric space ensures such a nicety?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you misunderstood the definition of connectedness:
A subset of a topological space $Z\subseteq X$ is disconnected if it can be divided into two nonenmpty disjoint *open in $Z$* sets $A_1,A_2$.

Recall that a set $A_i\subseteq Z$ is open in $Z$ if there is an open in $X$ set $B_i$ such that $A_i=B_i\cap Z$.

It is not required for the definition of connectedness that also the sets $B_i$ are disjoint.

It is of course a valid question (though not directly related with the definition of connectedness) whether a space $X$ has the property that in such cases you can always choose even $B_i$ to be disjoint.

If you only consider closed subsets $Z$ it happens that this is the case if and only if the space satisfies the $T_4$ separation axiom.

For arbitrary subsets $Z$, it holds if (and probably only if) the space satisfies even the $T_5$ separation axiom.

Metric spaces satisfy all $T_i$ separation axioms.

Answer (score 1):

Let us prove the assertion you doubted, and also the converse, i.e.:

> If $X$ is a topological space and $Y$ a subspace of $X$ and $A$ a subset of $Y,$ then $A$ is connected in $X$ iff it is connected in $Y.$

- By definition, *$A$ is connected in $X$ iff it is connected as a topological space*, when equipped with the subspace topology induced from $X$, i.e. the open subsets of $A$ are by definition the $U\cap A$'s where $U$ is any open subset of $X$.
- *The process of inducing topology on subsets is transitive*, i.e. on $A,$ the topology induced from that of $Y$ (which is itself induced from that of $X$) coincides with the topology directly induced from that of $X.$ Indeed, $(U\cap Y)\cap A=U\cap(Y\cap A)=U\cap A.$

These two points prove the claim. It means that connectedness is (like compactness) an absolute notion.