# Connectedness of a subspace?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I am new to topology and I am stuck at this basic question. Let $Y$ be a subspace of $X$ and A be a subset of Y. I need to show that

A is connected in Y $\iff$ A is connected in X.

$\Rightarrow$ is easy. If $A = C \cup D$, where $C$ and $D$ are disjoint open sets in X, then $Y \cap C = C$ and $Y \cap D = D$ and we get $C$ and $D$ are open sets in Y.

Can you help me with $\Leftarrow$?

Comment: Your definition of connected subset is wrong. Hence so is already your proof of $\Rightarrow.$ Can you please edit your post to include the correct definition?

Comment: Munkres topology defines a connected set saying X is a connected set if there is no separation, where a separation is a pair U, V of disjoint nonempty open subsets of X whose union is X. I think we can apply this definition to a subspace, because if Y is a subspace of X, Y has a subspace topology.

Comment: Can you please *edit your post* to include the correct definition of "$A$ is a connected *subset* of a *topological space* $X$"? (Not the definition of "a topological space $X$ is connected".)

Comment: See also the comments here: [Proof that connectedness is not relative to the set studied / Connectedness absolute notion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4673852).

Comment: You edited your post to add a *distinct* new question. Please focus on one question per post. And have a look at the links above to the 2 duplicates. They clarify your confusion about the definition of "A is connected in X" and answer your initial question.

Comment: Thank you I will make a separate question.

Comment: Your accepting the (erroneous) answer below shows that your confusion remains. Please look at the two duplicates linked above. They already answered your question. I added [a new answer in the duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4675515/386889) for clarification.

Comment: Your proof of $\Rightarrow$ is wrong because you started with "[...] $C$ and $D$ are disjoint open sets in $X$" instead of "$C$ and $D$ are disjoint and $C=C'\cap A,D=D'\cap A$ where $C',D'$ are open sets in $X$".